# Passing data from model to print into tcpdf in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file with some data in that I get from a query, the pdf creator is in the controller (TCPDF).

My storyboard :
I am using codeigniter to develop my php application. In my view, there is a table that every row have a button to create a pdf from information its row. I can preview it in modal bootstrap. 
Now , I am confused how to passed that information to pdf (TCPDF). 
Should i using GET or somrthing like that in my Controller ?
Or in modal ?

This is my view

```
<tbody>
  <?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach($data_request as $data) {
  ?>
   <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $no++.". ";?> </td>                                           
        <td class="sorting1"><?php echo $data['id_request'];?> </td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo date ("d-m-Y, H:i ",strtotime($data['time_start']));?></td>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $data['keluhan'];?></td>                                            
        <td class="center"><span class="label label-warning"><?php echo $data['status_request'];?></span></td> 
        <td class="center"><?php echo date ("d-m-Y, H:i ",strtotime($data['close_request']));?></td>                                                     <td  class="center">
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> Close
                </a>

                <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" id="print" req_id="<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>">
                    <i class="halflings-icon pencil"></i> Print  
                </a>         
        </td>
   </tr>

   <?php } ?>
   </tbody>

//This is my modal bootstrap preview :
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h1>Print Preview</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
           <p id="id_preview"> </p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
             <?php $id= $data['id_request'];?>
             <a href="<?php echo base_url().'control_closing/generate_pdf/id'; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Jadikan PDF</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>   
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is my controller

```
public function generate_pdf($idRequest){
    $this->model_request->selectOneRequest($idRequest);
    $this->load->library("TC_PDF");
    $pdf = new TC_Pdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Dzil');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Form Perbaikan / Permintaan');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TMS/DEPT/IT/06');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, form, perbaikan, Permintaan');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
    if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
        $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Ln(8);

    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Nama', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 5, '$data_pdf[nama]', "B", 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');


    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Departement', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 5, '', "B", 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');


    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'NIK', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 5, '', "B", 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');

    $pdf->Ln(4);


    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Permintaan / ', 0, 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Perbaikan  ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');

    $html = <<<EOD

    <form action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > &nbsp; Login    
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > &nbsp; Printer
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > &nbsp; Monitor
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > &nbsp; Computer
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > &nbsp; Network
        <input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > Lain-lain
    </form>
 EOD;

    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 1, false, 1);        


    $pdf->Ln(4);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Keluhan', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 90,' ', 0, 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');

    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Keterangan', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 60,' ', 0, 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');

    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, 'Catatan', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell( 2, 5, ': ', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell( 0, 10,' ', 0, 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Ln(4);

    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Tgl Permintaan / Paraf', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C'); //width, height, 
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, 'Persetujuan Manajer', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, 'Tgl Persetujuan', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, 'Diterima Oleh', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, 'Tgl Terima', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, 'Perkiraan Selesai', 1, 0, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, 'Tgl Selesai', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T'); //width, height, 
    $pdf->Cell(30, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 25, '', 1, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Cell(25, 25, '', 1, 1, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');
    $pdf->Ln(2);
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'TMS-IT-06 (10.2001)', 0, 0, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'T');

    // reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('example_057.pdf', 'I');


}
```

This is my model

```
public function selectOneRequest($id_request){
   $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_request', array('id_request'=>$id_request));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just construct the href of the link to point to the `generate_pdf` function.. assuming your controller name is `Tcpdf`

```
<a href="/tcpdf/generate_pdf/<?php echo $data['id_request']; ?>">Print</a>
```